# How to serialize params from controller into JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, .net-core

I need to serialize params from controller, like this:

```
public void GetData(String names, Messages messages)
{
    ...
}
```

Now I use reflection:

```
var controllers = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods()).ToList();
```

This is how I get the parameters of each controller.

Finally, I would like to get JSON Schema. I see it like this:

> Controller params -> JSON -> JSON Schema

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting. Can you share some sample output? And rephrase your question and issue you are facing?

Comment: you want return json data?

Comment: @liang.good yes

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You want to return a JSON schema of the parameters of the current action method that's being called? Looks like you want to generate documentation? Why don't you use Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

In normal asp.net core web you create a controller you can return like this:

```
public JsonResult GetData(string names,Messages messages)
{
    return Json(new {Name=names,Message=messages});
}
```

in asp.net core web api you can do it like this:

```
public IActionResult GetData(string names,Messages messages)
{
    return Ok(new {Name=names,Message=messages});
}
```

Comment: Thank! Unfortunately, I don't know the exact number of parameters. This is a parser that parses all controllers and serializes them to JSON

Comment: you want to return all the data to this controller but you do not know the name of them?